# svgjs how to replay and control series of animations using slider

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg.js

I am using [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/) and would like to play a series of animations and then provide a slider for the user to control the animation to look at it more closely. It looks like when an animation is complete, svg.js cleans up the resources so the situation gets nulled out so I can't reset it. I have a fiddle with a simplified example. After the animation plays once, I would like to then be able to use the slider and use the `at` method to reposition the animations.

https://jsfiddle.net/voam/xeajbhea/2/

```
var draw = SVG('drawing'),
  rectA1 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#f06'),
  rectA2 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#60f').translate(200),
  rectB1 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#ce0').translate(0, 100).opacity(0),
  rectB2 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#0ec').translate(200, 100).opacity(0);

var animation1 = rectA1.animate().move(200).opacity(0);
var animation2 = rectA2.animate().move(-200).opacity(0).during(function(pos) {
  document.getElementById("range_animation").value = pos;
});
var animation3, animation4;

animation2.after(function(situation) {

  animation3 = rectB1.animate().move(200).opacity(1);
  animation4 = rectB2.animate().opacity(1).move(-200)
    .during(function(pos) {
      document.getElementById("range_animation").value = 1 + pos;
    });
  console.log('animations', animation1, animation2, animation3, animation4);

});

document.getElementById("range_animation").addEventListener("change", function(el) {
  ///console.log('change', el, );
  var val = this.value;    

  if (animation1.situation) {
    if (val < 1) {
      animation1.at(val).pause();
      animation2.at(val).pause();
    } else {
      animation3.at(val - 1).pause();
      animation4.at(val - 1).pause();
    }
  }



}, false);
```

HTML below:

```
<div id="drawing">

</div>
<input type="range" id="range_animation" min="0.01" max="2" step=".01" value=".01">
```

Comment: What about creating the situation yourself and queue it so you can reuse it? So queue it, run the animation, queue again and use at?

Comment: Or try using loop(true) to loop the animation - the situation is not cleared in this case

Comment: @Fuzzyma From the first suggestion, I am not sure what you mean by "creating the situation yourself". Is there an example of this somewhere?

Comment: @Fuzzyma I have started to use the loop approach and using the during() callback to stop just before the end of the animation to link the different steps. I also tried using once(pos) but that didn't get called so reliably on the number I used (.99). For looping animations it would be nice to have on onComplete callback, when an iteration completed,  or for non looping animations an onBeforeComplete callback so one could pause the animation before it ends. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Everything is on svg.js is an object. Even the situation. So you can go and do `new SVG.Situation(parameters...)`. This object can be queued after with the corresponding method.

Comment: You can also animate SVGs with the browser's [web animation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API), without using an external library. I've written a short tutorial with example code [here](https://mb.sb/tech/animations/animations.html).

Answer (score 0):

One approach that works is as @Fuzzyma mentioned is to make the animations loop so they don't get terminated. Then one has to manage the transition sets from one to another. Any animations that don't get run immediately start in a paused state. In my real project not this demo there are 5 animation sets each with subanimations so lets see if this turns out to be manageable!

```
 var atEnd = function (pos) {

            var rounded = pos.toFixed(2);
            return  (rounded == .99 || rounded == 1.00);
        };

    var draw = SVG('drawing')
        , rectA1 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#f06')
        , rectA2= draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#60f').translate(200)
        , rectB1 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#ce0').translate(0, 100).opacity(0)
        , rectB2 = draw.rect(50, 50).fill('#0ec').translate(200, 100).opacity(0);

    var animation3, animation4, lastTotalRange;

    var animation1 = rectA1.animate().move(200).opacity(0).loop();
    var animation2 = rectA2.animate().move(-200).opacity(0).loop();

    animation2
        .during(function( pos ) {

            document.getElementById("range_animation").value = pos;

            if ( atEnd (pos) ) {

                animation2.pause();

                animation3 = rectB1.animate().move(200).opacity(1).loop();
                animation4 = rectB2.animate().opacity(1).move(-200).loop();

                animation4
                    .during(function( pos ) {

                        if (pos > 0) {
                            document.getElementById("range_animation").value = 1 + pos;
                        }


                        if (atEnd (pos)) {
                            animation4.pause();
                        }

                    });

                animation3.during( function(pos) {

                    if (atEnd (pos)) {
                        animation3.pause();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    animation1.during(function( pos ) {

        if (atEnd (pos)) {
            animation1.pause();
        }
    });

    $('input#range_animation').on('input', function() {
        $(this).trigger('change');
    })
    $('input#range_animation').on('change', function() {

        var val = $( this).val(),
            delta = 0;
        if (lastTotalRange) {
            delta = val - lastTotalRange;
        }
        if (val < 1) {
            animation1.at(val).pause();
            animation2.at(val).pause();
            if (lastTotalRange > 1) {
                animation3.at(.01);
                animation4.at(.01);
            }
        }
        else {
            animation3.at(val - 1).pause();
            animation4.at(val - 1).pause();
            if (lastTotalRange < 1) {
                animation1.at(.99);
                animation1.at(.99);
            }
        }
      //  console.log('totalAnimationRange:change', delta, val);

        lastTotalRange = val;
    })
```

and the html

```
<div id="drawing"></div>

<input type="range" id="range_animation" min="0.00" max="1.99" step=".01" value=".01">
```

and the jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle.net/voam/ob2bjfur/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/voam/ob2bjfur/1/)